# How to get access to the vuex in script part of components and pages in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

i'm on Nuxtjs 2.13 . i'm trying to load my components dynamically according to my `store.state.dir` .
like this:

```js
<script>
import store from 'Vuex';
let siteDirection = store.state.dir
const mm= ()=>import('~/components/'+ siteDirection +'/home/mm.vue')

export default {
  components:{
    'mm': mm
  
}
</script>
```

but i can't get access to my store. what sould i do?

my `store/index.js` file:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  dir: 'rtl'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given you did setup Vuex properly, you should be able to access the state on the global $store variable..

And you can not access or "dynamically" define or work with these variables outside the Vue scope..

So - to answer your question - change your code to this:

```
<script>
export default { 
  components:{
    'mm': () => import('~/components/'+ this.$store.state.dir + '/home/mm.vue')
}
</script>
```

Also your store/index.js should not `export const state` but something rather:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'    
Vue.use(Vuex)

const state = {
dir: 'rtl'
}

const store = new Vuex.store({
state,
// getters,mutations,actions,modules if you want
})

export default store
```

However, for whatever you're trying to achieve this would probably be considered an "un-conventional" way of accessing components but I have no idea what you're trying to achieve so, and this would be the response to the actual question.. But now you will have multiple sets of very similar components.

Comment: as developing a bidirectional app, I'm creating two components for each of my components on top level. one in `rtl` directory and one in `ltr` directory. and import and mount them according to my app `dir` stored in `vuex` . is it weird??

Comment: i've did `this.$store.state.dir` but it gives me `Cannot read property '$store' of undefined` . my vuex setup is as nuxt instructed, added `index.js` in `store` directory and exported `state` , `getters` , `mutations` , `actions` . actually i'm working fine with my `store` and used the same `this.$store.state.dir` in `created()` part of a components and every thing was fine

Comment: I'm not very familiar to nuxt, but I checked the question again and edited my response, you might want to check your store.js as well as per above, maybe this is the issue? As per your other question, what would be the difference the same component between rtl & ltr?

Answer (score 0):

As I tried different thing the only thing that worked for me was to use `<component :is="" />` and computed property:

```html
<template>
  <component :is="mycomp" />
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  computed:{
    mycomp(){
      return ()=>import('@/components/'+ this.$store.state.dir +'/mycomp.vue')
    }
  }
}
```